# jquery validation does not work on dynamically added input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

**EDITED to update to latest findings** When inserting a new INPUT on the form, I make sure to specify the INPUT to be required. I get the same classes attached to the input that works and the one that does not work. However the tooltip does not appear on the dynamically added input element and does work on the one that was there when tooltipster was applied on document ready.

What I was able to do is if I go through each newly created element and valid() it tooltip is shown and validation works correctly. Relying on form valid() skips newly added elements. Hopefully this is enough of requested code. I have tried inserting elements with and without "required" options. 
Is there something else that must be done? Final elements when expected look like this:

```
$("#save").click(function()
{
    setToolTips(); //make sure tooltipster is assigned to newly createde elements
    var addedValid = true;
    //needed to do validation on newly created elements
    $('input.added').each(function() { 
        if(!$(this).valid())
            addedValid = false;
    });

    if (!$('#create_project').valid() || !addedValid) return false;
    //irrelevant after this
 });

$(".add_milestone span ").click(function () {

    var html = '' +
        '<input data-rule-required="true" required="required" id="milestone_' + current_milestone + '" type="text" ' +
        '               class=" w250 error added" aria-required="true"  />' +
        '</div>';

    $(".items").append(html);
    current_milestone++;
});

function setToolTips(position) {
    if (position == 'undefined')
        position = 'right';
    $('form :input[required],:input[id="phone"]').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
        onlyOne: false, // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
        position: position,  // display the tips to the right of the element
        autoClose : true,
        hideOnClick : true,
        delay: 100,
        timer : 1200,
        theme: 'tooltipster-light'
    });
}

$("#save").click(function()
{
    setToolTips(); //make sure tooltipster is assigned to newly createde elements
    var addedValid = true;
    //needed to do validation on newly created elements
    $('input.added').each(function() { 
        if(!$(this).valid())
            addedValid = false;
    });

    if (!$('#create_project').valid() || !addedValid) return false;
    //irrelevant after this
 });

$(".add_milestone span ").click(function () {

    var html = '' +
        '<input data-rule-required="true" required="required" id="milestone_' + current_milestone + '" type="text" ' +
        '               class=" w250 error added" aria-required="true"  />' +
        '</div>';

    $(".items").append(html);
    current_milestone++;
});

function setToolTips(position) {
    if (position == 'undefined')
        position = 'right';
    $('form :input[required],:input[id="phone"]').tooltipster({
        trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
        onlyOne: false, // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
        position: position,  // display the tips to the right of the element
        autoClose : true,
        hideOnClick : true,
        delay: 100,
        timer : 1200,
        theme: 'tooltipster-light'
    });
}
```

Comment: I can verify that Tooltipster and jQuery Validate work nicely together.  But how can you possibly expect anyone to know where you made the mistakes without seeing any of your code?

Comment: Well, I was hoping it would be something that I am not doing for initialization. What I figured out is that validation is not triggered automatically on new elements during form.validate. If I do
        $('input.added').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).valid())
                addedValid = false;
        }); both validation and tooltipster works.

Comment: *"validation is not triggered automatically on new elements"* ~ That makes no sense and it's not how the plugin works.  Really, none of it make any sense without the context of your code!  Post the relevant code within your question and then post your answer below.  Otherwise, you might as well just delete the whole thing before it gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

I have review your code and find that You have used `$(this).valid()`
I think this is your mistake. You have to use form **`ID`** instead of **`$(this)`**

**So for ie :**

```
$('#formID').valid()
```

Comment: $(this).valid() - is when iterating through newly created elements in order to make it work. This was added because  i$('#create_project').valid() was not validating these elements.